# Array to string conversion in Drupal webform

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-webform

Before upgrading from Webfrom 7.3 to 7.4, this code used to work

```
 $html = $html . webform_submission_render($node, $submission, NULL, 'html');
```

My HTML would display and then the HTML from the submission would follow.

Now, it returns a page displaying the contents of $html and then prints Array after. Drupal gives me a "Notice: Array to string conversion". 
This is the HTML from that section on the page:

...16:16:22(/p)(/div)(br/)(br/)Array  (/div)

If I exclude the function and just leave the $html:

```
$html = $html
```

all the HTML is displayed correctly.

If I exclude the $html and just leave the function:

```
$html = webform_submission_render($node, $submission, NULL, 'html');
```

the submission is displayed correctly on the page, in HTML.
I then used dpm:

```
dpm(webform_submission_render($node, $submission, NULL, 'html') );
```

and it, in fact, returns ...(Array, 15 elements)

How do I get the array to actually convert to html before appending to the rest of the $html?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a bug in Webform 7.4. The `webform_submission_render()` function was changed in 7.4, and doesn't pass `$renderable` through `drupal_render()` before returning. Inserting `drupal_render()` into the function as before returns the correct HTML. Alternatively, assigning the `webform_submission_render()` to a variable and then passing it through `drupal_render()` in the custom code produces the same result.

```
$record = webform_submission_render($node, $submission, NULL, 'html');
$html = $html . drupal_render($record);
```